# Object having two different instances at method activation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

The title is not that clear, and if anybody has a better suggestion please tell me.
Now to business:
I am activating a class' method.

```
m_someObject.Clear();
```

The problem is that when I look at the address of `m_someObject` before the call I get that it is located in a certain address, and when I enter the `Clear` method with the debugger I get that `this` variable is located in another address.
The result is that after returning from `Clear` method it doesn't seem to have affected
`m_someObject` instance which called it.
Does anybody have any idea what could cause this kind of behavior?
Working on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64-bit.

Comment: Do you have a Java or C# background?

Comment: I guessed that you may be passing m_someObject around to functions by value, which, for the same syntax, has different semantics in C# and Java.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you pass `m_someObject` as a value to some other function (and thus get a copy) and execute `Clear()` only on copy. This way you will not notice a change on original object.

Comment: I am going step by step with the debugger, before entering (and after exiting) the Clear method m_someObject has one one address and inside the method it has another..

Comment: What is the difference between your code and this snippet? http://ideone.com/WP091

Comment: It isn't only this code prints the same address for both cases, and mine doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you have two different variables with the same name? One defined in the immediate scope and another one, maybe in the global scope?

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently the debugger was lying.. I wasn't aware of this, but apparently some of the code was compiled in release mode. Conclusion - Debugger No, printf - Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason is Multiple Inheritance. Unlike C# and Java, in C++ a class can have multiple base classes. Obviously, not all can be located at offset 0. This means that `this` has to be adjusted if you're using a method from a base class that's located at a non-zero offset.